# How to import text from a web page to a single cell

Tags: vba, excel

```
Dim lastRow As Integer
lastRow = Range("a1").End(xlDown).Row
Dim url As String

    For i = 2 To lastRow Step 1
        strUrl = Range("a" & i).Value

        With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;https://politicsandwar.com/api/nation/id=" & strUrl, Destination:=Range("S" & i))
        End With
    Next
```

I want to pull the full text from a  particular website into a single cell. When I run this, my screen greys out for a minute or two and doesn't actually put anything in the destination cells. For example, the first row (cell `A2`) would be using data from `"7687"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `.Refresh` as the last statement within the `With ... End With` block, like this:

```
For i = 2 To lastRow Step 1
    strUrl = Range("a" & i).Value

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;https://politicsandwar.com/api/nation/id=" & strUrl, Destination:=Range("S" & i))
        .Refresh
    End With
Next
```

Take a look at [this](https://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s393/query-table.htm).

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ie As Object
    Dim retStr As String

    Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

    With ie
        .Navigate "http://www.wikihow.com/Choose-an-Email-Address"
        .Visible = True
    End With

    Do While ie.readystate <> 4: Wait 5: Loop

    DoEvents

    retStr = ie.document.body.innerText

    '~> Write the above to a text file
    Dim filesize As Integer
    Dim FlName As String

    '~~> Change this to the relevant path
    'Save as Text File
    'FlName = "C:\Users\Siddharth\Desktop\Sample.Txt"

    Range("A1").Value = retStr

    filesize = FreeFile()

    'Open FlName For Output As #filesize

    'Print #filesize, retStr
    Close #filesize
End Sub

Private Sub Wait(ByVal nSec As Long)
    nSec = nSec + Timer
    While nSec > Timer
        DoEvents
    Wend
End Sub
```

Based on this.

[Return entire page text from IE object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44746570/return-entire-page-text-from-ie-object/44746846#44746846)